# Internet problems. Figuring out if it's wifi or isp issue

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I recently moved house and ever since I did I've been having internet problems. I'm using wifi to connect to the network and I've been experiencing the following issues:

- High jitter
- High ms fluctuations and lag spikes in online games
- Being kicked out of the network and when reconnecting staying on
  "Identifying..." for some time.

I'm using Windows 7 and my wifi version is 802.11a.
What I'm trying to figure out is whether the problem is on my end, ie wifi issues, or if the issue is on the ISP's end and I should call them.
Unfortunately I'm not able to connect directly to the router using a cable so I can't test where the problem lies using that.
I did try taking the laptop right next to the router to make sure the distance doesn't affect any measurements but as the problems are not constant I could only confirm that the high jitter was not caused by being a bit far from the router.
If anyone has any idea on how to figure out what the problem is I would be most grateful.

Comment: You don't mention which version of wifi you're using (different capabilities).  However, recognize that the distance ratings are limits under perfect circumstances.  A bigger influence can be the path between the router and your computer.  Walls, floors, ductwork, utility lines, major appliances, etc. can degrade the signal.  Think of the house in 3D and place the router where there is the least obstructed path for the signal.

Comment: My wifi version is 802.11a, I'll add it to the main post too. If something interferes with the signal it will be constant low quality, right? I mean it won't work correctly for 2 hours then kick me then work again for like 30 minutes etc etc. If it is indeed some sort of interference, shouldn't the quality be great if I move the laptop right next to the router?

Comment: 802.11a is extremely old.  You should expect zero performance if your connecting in this mode.  Its no shocked, at all, your having performance problems with 802.11a

Comment: 802.11a is the least capable version.  In terms of consistency, the physical obstructions don't change, but somebody turning on a microwave oven in the path or a neighbor with a strong signal could cause changing interference.  Testing with the laptop right next to the router will often give worse performace than testing from across the room if you are trying to determine whether the problem is hardware.

Comment: I've never had issues before though, it just started when I connected to this router. Should I just buy a usb wifi adapter and see if it fixes the problems?

Comment: Hold on, I'm a bit confused, the specs of the wifi card say "802.11a/b/g/n".

Comment: That means the card is capable of working with any of those versions of wifi.  The performance of the connection will be limited by the device with the lowest version.